# Several tests/test cases in one project using Robotium

Tags: android, robotium, ui-testing

I'm writing many tests for my Android application, meaning that there are about 15 tests cases. how can I implement them all? I tried to make several .java files in the same project for each testcase, but it ran only the first one. Then I made one Test,java and wrote several method inside it. like `public  void test1() throws Exception{...} public  void test2() throws Exception{...}` . But it also ran just the first test case. In Run Configurations I chose Run all tests in the selected project, while running I could see them all under JUnit window on the left part of the screen, it successfully ran the first, showed that the next is in process but it did nothing((((

Answer (score 2):

Remember to use solo.finishOpenedActivities() in your tearDown(). Then the execution will not hang.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using robotium to perform black box testing this is how ur class should look like:

```
public class TestAPK extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {

private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID="com.android.example";//your package name
private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME="com.android.example.MainActivity"; //your main activity full class name

private static Class launcherActivityClass;
static{
    try{
        launcherActivityClass=Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public TestAPK() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    super(TARGET_PACKAGE_ID,launcherActivityClass);
}
private Solo solo;


protected void setUp() throws Exception{
    solo=new Solo(getInstrumentation(),getActivity());
}
public void test1() throws Exception{...} 
public void test2() throws Exception{...}
}
```